# Dictionary is not getting save in Userdefault in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following test code

```
 if let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary{
 print(responseJSON)

 UserDefaults.standard.setValue(responseJSON, forKey: "user_auth_token")
//UserDefaults.standard.set(responseJSON, forKey: "user_auth_token")
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_auth_token")!)")

}
```

but at  "UserDefaults.standard.setValue" this line it gives me error that

```
for key user_auth_token'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ab06fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112ad3ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ab0555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001139cb82b _CFPrefsValidateValueForKey + 283
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001139cbc95 -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:copyValues:removeValuesForKeys:count:from:] + 373
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001139cbfbc -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:copyValues:from:] + 28
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001139cc013 -[CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:from:] + 67
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113aa759e __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 318
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113aa6e0a normalizeQuintuplet + 314
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113aa7454 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 100
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113a843fb -[_CFXPreferences setValue:forKey:appIdentifier:container:configurationURL:] + 91
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113a88065 _CFPreferencesSetAppValueWithContainer + 117
    12  Foundation                          0x00000001125bd563 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 55
)
```

what does it mean?.How can I store my data into user default.
please help.

Comment: Why are using `NSDictionary`? Instead you can use `[String: Any]` or `Dictionary<Any, Any>`.

Comment: @ Mahendra- I tried[String: Any] instead of NSDictionary,still its giving me error

Comment: is there any custom object in dictionary?

Comment: @ Mahendra- No,its just a simple Api Response

Comment: can you show what data has your api.

Comment: You can't save Dictionary objects directly to the user defaults, you still have to convert it into something that is storable. You actually can store `Data` as an easy workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You need to store & retrieve JSON from userDefaults like this, just need to archive the data while saving custom objects. Moreover if you want to save custom class objects in user defaults , you need to implement NSCoding/ Codeable protocol in that class.

```
class func saveInUserDefauld(json: [String: Any]) {
    let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: json)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(myData, forKey: "UserSession")
}

class func getUser()-> [String: Any]? {
    if let user = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UserSession")as? Data {
        let recovedUserJson = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: user) as! [String: Any]
        return recovedUserJson
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```